# data type in Julia and MLJ

Tags: machine-learning, julia

I am new to Julia and trying to fit a simple classification tree

Packages import and env activation:

```
using Pkg 
Pkg.activate(".")

using CSV
using DataFrames
using Random
using Downloads
using ARFFFiles
using ScientificTypes
using DataFramesMeta
using DynamicPipe
using MLJ
using MLJDecisionTreeInterface
```

Data:

```
titanic_reader  = CSV.File("/home/andrea/dev/julia/titanic.csv"; header = 1);
titanic = DataFrame(titanic_reader);

# remove missing values
titanic =  dropmissing(titanic);


titanic = @transform(titanic, 
    :class=categorical(:class), 
    :sex=categorical(:sex),  
    :survived=categorical(:survived)
    );
```

Check the data

```
first (titanic , 3)

3×4 DataFrame
 Row │ class  sex     age      survived 
     │ Cat…   Cat…    Float64  Cat…     
─────┼──────────────────────────────────
   1 │ 3      male       22.0  N
   2 │ 1      female     38.0  Y
   3 │ 3      female     26.0  Y
```

Check the data schema

```
schema(titanic);


┌──────────┬───────────────┬───────────────────────────────────┐
│ names    │ scitypes      │ types                             │
├──────────┼───────────────┼───────────────────────────────────┤
│ class    │ Multiclass{3} │ CategoricalValue{Int64, UInt32}   │
│ sex      │ Multiclass{2} │ CategoricalValue{String7, UInt32} │
│ age      │ Continuous    │ Float64                           │
│ survived │ Multiclass{2} │ CategoricalValue{String1, UInt32} │
└──────────┴───────────────┴───────────────────────────────────┘
```

Schema seems ok to me

Prepare data for modelling:

```
# target and features
y, X = unpack(titanic, ==(:survived), rng = 123);

# partitiont training & test 
(X_trn, X_tst), (y_trn, y_tst)  = partition((X, y), 0.75, multi=true,  rng=123);
```

Fit the model:

```
# model
mod = @load DecisionTreeClassifier pkg = "DecisionTree" ;
fm = mod() ;
fm_mach = machine(fm, X_trn, y_trn);
```

and here is the problem:

```
Warning: The number and/or types of data arguments do not match what the specified model
│ supports. Suppress this type check by specifying `scitype_check_level=0`.
│ 
│ Run `@doc DecisionTree.DecisionTreeClassifier` to learn more about your model's requirements.
│ 
│ Commonly, but non exclusively, supervised models are constructed using the syntax
│ `machine(model, X, y)` or `machine(model, X, y, w)` while most other models are
│ constructed with `machine(model, X)`.  Here `X` are features, `y` a target, and `w`
│ sample or class weights.
│ 
│ In general, data in `machine(model, data...)` is expected to satisfy
│ 
│     scitype(data) <: MLJ.fit_data_scitype(model)
│ 
│ In the present case:
│ 
│ scitype(data) = Tuple{Table{Union{AbstractVector{Continuous}, AbstractVector{Multiclass{3}}, AbstractVector{Multiclass{2}}}}, AbstractVector{Multiclass{2}}}
│ 
│ fit_data_scitype(model) = Tuple{Table{<:Union{AbstractVector{<:Continuous}, AbstractVector{<:Count}, AbstractVector{<:OrderedFactor}}}, AbstractVector{<:Finite}}
└ @ MLJBase ~/.julia/packages/MLJBase/eCnWm/src/machines.jl:231
```

Clearly when fitting the model:

```
fit!(fm_mach)
```

I get an error

```
[ Info: It seems an upstream node in a learning network is providing data of incompatible scitype. See above. 
ERROR: ArgumentError: Unordered CategoricalValue objects cannot be tested for order using <. Use isless instead, or call the ordered! function on the parent array to change this
Stacktrace:
```

I am almost sure the error depends on the data type specification but, I cannot work the solution out.

Answer (score 1):

I can replicate your issue by using the Titan dataset from the MLJ function OpenML:

```
using MLJ
import DataFrames as DF
import DataFramesMeta as DFM

table = OpenML.load(42638)
```

and then cleaning it a bit to get exactly the same dataset you are using:

```
titanic =  DF.dropmissing(titanic);
DF.rename!(titanic, "pclass"=>"class")
titanic = titanic[:,[:class,:sex,:survived,:age]] # select only the fields you are using

titanic = DFM.@transform(titanic, 
    :class=categorical(:class), 
    :sex=categorical(:sex),  
    :survived=categorical(:survived)
    );
```

Now the issue is that the `DecisionTreeClassifier` model from  the `DeicisonTree` package is very efficient (fast!) but it requires *ordered* data only.

In this case you could perhaps coerce the `class` as an ordered field. An alternative is to use the `DecisionTreeClassifier` model from `BetaML`, that at the cost of being a bit slower can use any kind of input, including the Missing ones (so no need to drop them or use only that few fields - the original `titan` dataset has many more fields):

```
mod = @load DecisionTreeClassifier pkg = "BetaML" ;
fm = mod() ;
fm_mach = machine(fm, X_trn, y_trn);
fit!(fm_mach)

yhat_trn = mode.(predict(fm_mach , X_trn))
accuracy(y_trn,yhat_trn) # 0.91

yhat_tst = mode.(predict(fm_mach , X_tst))
accuracy(y_tst,yhat_tst) # 0.78
```

Note that there is a nice tutorial exactly on fitting the Titan database with Decision Tree and MLJ here: https://forem.julialang.org/mlj/julia-boards-the-titanic-1ne8 .